# Android Room database not informing me for live data changes

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I am using `Room Database` in my app. I am binding a list with a table in db and looking for update this list in realtime when any changes (insert/update) occur in specific table of room database.

**My Dao class**

```
@Dao
interface RecordsDao {
@Query("Select * from Records WHERE app_uuid = :appUUID")
fun getRecords(appUUID: String): List<Records>

@Insert
fun insertRecord(records: Records): Long

@Query("UPDATE Records SET detect_count = detect_count + 1 WHERE time_slot = :timeSlot and other_uuid = :otherUUID and app_uuid = :appUUID")
fun updateRecord(timeSlot: Int, appUUID: String, otherUUID: String)

@Query("Select * from Records WHERE app_uuid = :appUUID Order by detect_count desc")
fun getLiveRecords(appUUID: String): LiveData<List<Records>>
```

}

**Class for binding list**

```
 dbHelper?.recordsDao()?.getLiveRecords(sharedPrefUtil?.getAppStringPrefByKey(R.string.key_uuid)!!)
        ?.observe(this, object : Observer<List<Records>> {
            override fun onChanged(t: List<Records>?) {
                Log.e("MyApp", "Chaged fired");
            }
        })
```

**DBhelper Class**

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Records :: class), version = 1)
abstract class DBHelper : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun recordsDao(): RecordsDao
companion object {
    fun getDBHelper(context: Context): DBHelper {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, DBHelper::class.java, "MyAppPackageName")
            .allowMainThreadQueries().build()
    }
}
}
```

**Foreground service**

```
if (!dbHelper.recordsDao().isRecordExist(
                            slot,
                            sharedPrefUtil?.getAppStringPrefByKey(R.string.key_uuid)!!,
                            entry
                    )
            ) {
                Log.e("MyApp", entry + " record does not exist in db. INserting")
                val record = Records(
                        0,
                        slot,
                        sharedPrefUtil?.getAppStringPrefByKey(R.string.key_uuid)!!,
                        entry,
                        1,
                        currentDt
                )
                dbHelper.recordsDao().insertRecord(record)
            } else {
                Log.e("MyApp", entry + " record exist in db. UPdating")
                dbHelper.recordsDao().updateRecord(
                        slot,
                        sharedPrefUtil?.getAppStringPrefByKey(R.string.key_uuid)!!,
                        entry
                )
            }
        }
```

Here in in service i am updating/inserting records in table and listening for data changed in another class where i am binding list to table. Data insert/update successfully occurring but class that listen for changes in table does not get any response.

what else i am missing ? Please suggest

Comment: Is service  running in the same process?

Comment: yes, a foreground service is running in app

Comment: you know that even if service is in the same app it may run in different process? also is `AppDatabase` a singleton?

Comment: @Selvin please look at edit. I have added `DBHelper` class code. It is not singlton. I am creating new instance in every class/activity

Comment: please provide minimal example where `onChanged` is not working as it's working for me